# Drop down menu with jquery, php, mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am fairly new to programming so if you can include explanations so I can learn as I go will be very appreciated.

Ok So I am making a drop down menu from sql tables and I am using php and Jquery. So far I have gotten my first sub menu which is states to populate from my country menu. Now I am getting confused on how to get my city menu to populate from my state menu.

Here is my main php file!

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#flip").click(function() {
            jQuery("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        });

        jQuery("#country").change(function() {
            //jQuery("#address").val(jQuery("#courseid :selected").val());
            var querystr = 'countryid='+jQuery('#country :selected').val();
            jQuery.post("<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/CountryStateCity Drop Down/ajax.php", querystr, function(data){
                if(data.errorcode == 0){
                    jQuery('#statecbo').html(data.chtml)
                    //jQuery('#citydescr').append('<textarea name="citydescr" id="citydescr" cols="80" rows="3" maxlength="500"></textarea>')
                }else{
                    jQuery('#statecbo').html(data.chtml)
                }
            }, "json");
        });
    });
</script>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dynamic Drop Down Menu</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrap">
        <h5> Country</h5>
         <select id="country" name="country" required>
             <option value="">--Select Country--</option>
            <?php
            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from country order by name");
            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                $countryID=$row['IDCountry'];
                $countryname=$row['name'];
                echo "<option value='$countryID'>$countryname</option>";
             }
             ?>
             </select>
         </div>
        <h5>State</h5>
        <div class="wrap"  id="statecbo">



        </div>

        <div class="wrap">
             <h5>City</h5>

    </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

And here is my ajax.php file

```
$country_id = isset($_POST['countryid']) ? $_POST['countryid'] : 0;
if ($country_id <> 0) {
$errorcode = 0;
$strmsg = "";
$sql="SELECT * from state WHERE IDCountry = ". $country_id . " ORDER BY name;";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$cont=mysql_num_rows($result);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    $chtml = '<select name="states" id="states"><option value="0">--Select State--     </option>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $chtml .= '<option value="'.$row['IDState'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
    }
    $chtml .= '</select>';
    echo json_encode(array("errorcode"=>$errorcode,"chtml"=>$chtml));
}else{
    $errorcode = 1;
    $strmsg = '<font style="color:#F00;">No States available</font>';
    echo json_encode(array("errorcode"=>$errorcode,"chtml"=>$strmsg));
}


}
```

So my next step would be to add a city menu that is populated by the state menu I just populated from the country menu. Sorry if that is confusing. Thanks!

Based of off jeroen response here is what I added to try and get the city drop down menu.

My main php file--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#flip").click(function() {
            jQuery("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        });

        jQuery("#country").change(function() {

            var querystr = 'countryid='+jQuery('#country :selected').val();
            jQuery.post("<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/CountryStateCity Drop Down/ajax.php", querystr, function(data){
                if(data.errorcode == 0){
                    jQuery('#statecbo').html(data.chtml)

                }else{
                    jQuery('#statecbo').html(data.chtml)
                }
            }, "json");
        });
        jquery(".wrap").on('change', '#states',function() {
            var querystr = 'stateid=' +jQuery('#states :selected').val();
            jquery.post("<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/CountryStateCity Drop Down/ajax.php", querystr, function(data) {
                if(data.errorcode ==0){
                    jQuery('#citycbo').html(data.chtml)
                }else{
                    jQuery('#citycbo').html(data.chtml)
                }
            }, "json");
        });
    });
</script>
```

and my ajax.php file

```
$country_id = isset($_POST['countryid']) ? $_POST['countryid'] : 0;
if ($country_id <> 0) {
$errorcode = 0;
$strmsg = "";
$sql="SELECT * from state WHERE IDCountry = ". $country_id . " ORDER BY name;";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$cont=mysql_num_rows($result);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    $chtml = '<select name="states" id="states"><option value="0">--Select State--</option>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $chtml .= '<option value="'.$row['IDState'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
    }
    $chtml .= '</select>';
    echo json_encode(array("errorcode"=>$errorcode,"chtml"=>$chtml));
}else{
    $errorcode = 1;
    $strmsg = '<font style="color:#F00;">No States available</font>';
    echo json_encode(array("errorcode"=>$errorcode,"chtml"=>$strmsg));
}


}

$state_id = isset($_POST['IDState']) ? $_POST['IDState'] : 0;
if ($state_id <> 0) {
$errorcode = 0;
$strmsg = "";
$sql="SELECT * from state WHERE IDState = ". $state_id . " ORDER BY name;";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$cont=mysql_num_rows($result);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    $chtml = '<select name="city" id="city"><option value="0">--Select city--  </option>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $chtml .= '<option value="'.$row['IDCity'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
    }
    $chtml .= '</select>';
    echo json_encode(array("errorcode"=>$errorcode,"chtml"=>$chtml));
}else{
    $errorcode = 1;
    $strmsg = '<font style="color:#F00;">No city available</font>';
    echo json_encode(array("errorcode"=>$errorcode,"chtml"=>$strmsg));
}


}
```

Comment: The `mysql_` functions are deprecated. You should use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead. Also your script is wide open to SQL injections.

Comment: How would I go about displaying results from my last drop down selection in a editable text box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically do the same thing you have done with the country / states.

However, you are using the jQuery `change()` function so that will not work with elements that were not on the page when that function was registered.

You can solve that by using event delegation:

```
jQuery(".wrap").on('change', '#states', function() {
  // do your stuff
}
```

I have used the `.wrap` element as that is the one that wraps your form elements, but you could also use `document` for example.

And you can of course use the same method for what you have already, just change:

```
jQuery("#country").change(function() {
```

to:

```
jQuery(".wrap").on('change', '#country', function() {
```

Comment: OK thanks for the help so far, But I still can not get my city menu to populate. To be honest I am not sure on what I am doing, It took me along time to get my first two menus working. I will add an update to my oridinal code on what I added if you would still be willing to help.

Comment: How would I go about displaying the results in a editable text file from my last drop down menu?